# Android SQLite insert 2 rows with same id

Tags: android, sqlite

I insert 2 records in the table at the same time, which has the ID field AUTOINCREMENT. can be assigned to the second record id before? so that when I delete a record using the id are deleted both?

Comment: If you haven't set Primary attribute with your ID, you can insert 2 same values for different rows manually.
'ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("id", id);'
When you will not add id manually, then it will add id automatically in that row.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can assign the same ID to 2 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want two different rows with the same ID and the ID field has AUTOINCREMENT enabled you cannot give them the same ID. That'd be a bad idea for several reasons.

I think what you should rather do is rethink your database and/or table structure. I'd propose you put the rows in different tables and make one of the rows depend on the other. Then you can make them have the same ID in their tables and have one ID to delete both rows in the different tables.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution? every time I put 2 records together that have related information, so if I delete one, I also have to delete the next one.

Comment: @DeboraCarnevali I don't see how that would make my proposal invalid. If these records relate, it is fine to have them in two different tables with the same ID. Then you could do the something like the following to delete them:
      DELETE t, tb
      FROM table t
      JOIN table_b tb ON tb.id = t.id
      AND t.id 1

Comment: ok, I know the Join. But I have 6 tables in the database and do not want to create another. Thanks anyway, I accept your answer

Comment: @DeboraCarnevali Why do you hesitate to create another table?